# How can I get the length of text entered in a textbox using java?

Tags: java

How can I get the length of text entered in a textbox using java ?
I tried using this code but it's not working fine:

```
if(textField1.getText().length()==2)
label1.setText="2";
```

Comment: How does it work exactly in your use case? Throws exception? Returns false number? Something third?

Comment: What it returns to you?

Comment: Maybe the length of the text isn't 2 ....

Comment: Shouldn't it be `label1.setText("2");`?

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine except it shows the length only when it is 2. In the rest of cases it will continue to show 2 because it changes only for "2" number. Better do this

```
label1.setText(""+textField1.getText().length());
```

Comment: This will not work. `setText` is not a variable in Java.

Comment: Sorry, of course it is not. It's method and I had updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `setText` is a method and not a variable, hence you cannot use the assignment operator.
You should update the code to:

```
if(textField1.getText().length()==2)
    label1.setText("2");
```

If you want to do the same for all lengths, you can simply write:

```
label1.setText(""+textField1.getText().length());
```

Comment: Mind that also the label probably had an empty text initially, so the layouted size must be sufficient. (`label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 24));` when too small)

Comment: The OP has not clarified the question and we still don't know what _it's not working fine_ means. How do you now that `label1` is not a custom object with a public String field named `setText`? :)

Comment: @DraganBozanovic True that the question is relatively unclear. And this is my point of view. The OP is free to reject this answer and correct me in case this is a misinterpretation of his question. But I think `label1` refers to a JLabel and that he is trying to set the text in it in Java. Again, I might be completely wrong.